# Why is PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager providing increasingly slow connections?

Tags: java, http, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using **httpClient 4.3.6**, with a `CloseableHttpClient` served by a `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`.

My current setup consists of 200 threads concurrently executing GET requests through the client. I'm trying to maximize the number of requests the threads can handle per second, but as soon as I start executing more than ~100/s, the `httpClient.execute()` requests start taking more and more time to return. I know for a fact that the machine serving the requests is not slowing down, and that the source of the problems lies in the httpClient library or in the resources on my machine.

This is my instantiation of the client

```
    // Start up an eviction thread.
    // remove idle (for 50ms) connections every 50 ms
    IdleConnectionMonitorThread monitor = new IdleConnectionMonitorThread(cm);
    // Don't stop quitting.
    monitor.setDaemon(true);
    monitor.start();

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    // increase connection limit
    cm.setMaxTotal(2000);
    cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(2000);
    // create client
    HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    builder.setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom().build());
    builder.setConnectionManager(cm);
    this.httpClient = builder.build();
```

The mean execution time of the `execute` method increases steadily but slowly when I start the threads' execution, and drops quickly as soon as the requests rate goes down.

```
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(uri);
    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();

    try(CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest, context);) {

        int returnStatus = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        switch (returnStatus){
        case 404:
            // deal with 404
        case 200:
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                    entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                try{
                    // deal with instream
                } finally {
                    instream.close();
                    // make sure everything is consumed
                    EntityUtils.consume(entity);
                }
            } else {
                // throw exception
            }
        default:
            // weird codes
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it makes sense to have so many concurrent connections. How many cores do you have? Maybe you should use asynchronous http client to prevent threads fighting for resources.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the `IdleConnectionMonitorThread` is the culprit. It grabs the pool look every 50 ms effectively blocking out all worker threads, which spend most of their time waiting on the pool lock instead of doing anything useful.

The connection monitor should probably be sweeping the pool not more frequently than once every 30 seconds. If you want to limit total connection life time you should be using TTL (time to live) parameter of the pooling connection manager instead.